# Ошибка парсинга Python

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

Необходимо на [этой](http://www.emu-land.net/consoles/dendy/roms?act=showonly&id=139) странице получить список данных из блока **список**:

Я вытащил ссылку и выполнил запрос requests

В итоге в requests.content вернулось это:

```
b'Battle City (J)\r<br>Battle City (J) [o1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p1][o1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p1][o2]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p1][o3]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p1][T+Rus1.1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p2]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p2][o1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p3]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p3][T+Rus1.1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p4]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p4][o1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [p4][T+Rus1.1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Chi]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Chi][a1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Chi][a2]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Chi][a3]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Gre1.0_Vag]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Rus]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Rus][a1]\r<br>Battle City (J) [T+Rus][a1][o1]\r<br>Battle City (VS)\r<br>Battle City (VS) [p1][!]\r<br>Battle City (VS) [p1][o1]\r<br>Battle City (VS) [p2]\r<br>Battle City by Zergkerrigan (Hack)\r<br>Battle City with 6 Enemies (Hack)\r<br>Making Love (Battle City Hack)\r<br>Making Love (Battle City Hack) [o1]\r<br>Missile Tank (Ch)\r<br>Missile Tank with 6 Enemies (Ch)\r<br>PCGC Tank (Battle City Chinese Hack)\r<br>Romman Love (Battle City Hack)\r<br>Romman Love (Battle City Hack) [o1]\r<br>Tank (Battle City Hack)\r<br>Tank 1990 (Ch)\r<br>\n'
```

Так как я использовал lxml попытался найти блоки br и отобразить их

```
html = get_html(r.content)
brs = html.cssselect("br")
for br in brs:
    print(br.text)
```

В итоге вернуло None у всех элементов.

Решил перейти на bs4 на html.parser, так как он позволяет парсить невалидный html.

soup Вернуло:

```
<br/> и куча пробелов
```

поиск по br и выводе вернуло:

```
brs = soup.find_all("br")
for br in brs:
print(br)

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
....
```

Интересно, как его спарсить? Как я понял, это из-за отсутствия основной структуры html (html, body, head).
Не охота из-за одного пункта на Selenium переписывать

Answer (score 1):

Смотря на код, сразу подумал, что можно получить полезное:

```
parsed_body="b'Battle City (J)\r<br>Tank 1990 (Ch)\r<br>\n'"
print('\n'.join(parsed_body.split('<br>')))
```

Простите, элегантнее было бы на regex, если понадобится для примера напишу

В данном случае, даже requests.content читается

```
parsed_body.xpath("./html/body/text()[5]")
```

Но вот попробуйте немного универсальный для исследования способ:

```
driver.get("...")
responsetext=driver.page_source

from lxml import html

parsed_body = html.fromstring(responsetext)
mdata = parsed_body.xpath("./html/body")
for uni in mdata:
        try:
            print uni.text_content().encode('utf-8')
            print uni.keys()
            pass
        except:
            pass    
        try:
            print uni.get('href').encode('utf-8')
            persons.append(uni.get('href').encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass
        try:
            from lxml import etree   
            print(etree.tostring(uni, encoding='utf-8'))
        except:
            pass
```

Этот блок кода, подчеркиваю, только для исследования возникшей проблемы (UI контент, подгрузка контента и т.п), а не для повседневного применения.

Надеюсь, что эти примеры будут подходящими ;)

По Вашей ссылке я прошел и понял, в чем затруднение. **У Вас элементарный случай, когда надо выполнить Javascript и дождаться загрузки страницы**
Изначально список файлов пустой.

```
<div class="filelist" id="mfile_139" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Придется кликнуть на кнопку (иначе, как вариант, еще, выполнить скрипт в selenium), дождаться загрузки, а потом парсить список файлов

```
<span class="hand" onclick="mfile('/consoles/dendy/roms?act=getmfile&amp;id=139','mfile_139'); return false;" title="Скачать">Загрузить</span>
```

Этот код сработает на ЭТОЙ странице, по Вашей ссылке. Появится возможность получить список ссылок на файлы, которые возможно скачать. Но далее придется подсчитывать количество файлов в списке, как минимум.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="hand"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mfile_139']/a")))
responsetext=driver.page_source
```

Нужен что-то уточнить? Возможно, я внимание Ваше рассеял) Возьмите последний абзац кода и начните с него)

Comment: первый вариант не срабатывает r = r.content
                        test = '\n'.join(r.split('<br>'))
                        print("Ололо:", test)

Comment: Напомню, все в разы проще надо выполнить Javascript и дождаться загрузки страницы. если непонятна последовательность, весь код покажу.  Но надо всего три строчки добавить после driver.get()

Comment: Насчет списка, что он пустой вы ошибаетесь, просмотрите запрос, который отправляется пр нажатии на список, вы увидите что приходит html, а не javascript, не вижу надобности в selenium

Comment: Очевидно (скриншот), что список файлов подгружается после нажатия на кнопку. https://i.imgur.com/LM5ojZB.png

Comment: вы пытаетесь получить данные с этой же страницы, который выполняется при нажатии на кнопку (ajax get) запрос. Теперь перейдите на эту страницу http://www.emu-land.net/consoles/dendy/roms?act=filelist&id=139 и скажите для чего мне использовать selenium? Данные в нормальном (относительно) виде, без javascript, к тому же я написал, что я вытащил ссылку и выполнил для нее запрос

Comment: Поэтому , верно, приходит html. Пришел html - пора выполнять скрипт, чтобы появился дополнительный html (cписсок ссылок на файлы) Selenium удобен тем, что скрипт может выполнять. Подождали выполнения скрипта, появился нужный-полный html? Пора из него получать ссылки

Comment: Не спорю) Ваш случай - получить список файлов http://www.emu-land.net/consoles/dendy/roms?act=filelist&id=139

Comment: данные уже в requests.content, зачем ожидать данные?

Comment: А я возможно пытаюсь не список файлов, а файл получить http://www.emu-land.net/consoles/dendy/roms?act=getmfile&id=139&fid=5   Нюансов я не знаю, извините. Задачи 8 миллионов файлов получить за час - такой задачи нет)

Comment: мне нужно только список названий файлов

Comment: Ок)   print('\n'.join(parsed_body.split('<br>')))

Comment: в первом комментарии я написал, что данный код не срабатывает для requests.content

Comment: Простите, если название файла из списка например New_Year_Tanks [Hack v2.1 by Sprill & Greyson].7z , тогда я просто предложил свой вариант решения вопроса)

Comment: кажется я понял в чем не понимание, нужно получить данные, которые открываются при нажатии на список, а не на загрузить

Comment: Да, все в порядке.  Ссылки .//*[@id='mfile_139']/a/@href

Текст ссылок .//*[@id='mfile_139']/a/text()

Comment: @BlayWhille прочитайте предыдущее мое сообщение. Там имеются 2 списка (Список и Загрузить). Нужно получить именно Список

Answer (score 0):

Получилось что-то в этом роде:

```
r = requests.get(url_files)
r = r.content
contents = r.split(b'<br>')
for line in contents:
    new = line.decode("utf-8")
    print(new)
```